# Error MSB4018 The "HotRestart.Tasks.DetectSigningIdentity" task failed unexpectedly Using .net maui application

Tags: .net-core, maui, maui-blazor, .net-maui, maui-community-toolkit

.Net Maui application not deploying in iphone physical device using windows machine. Paired both the laptop windows and Macbook air. Getting the following error.

````
Error   MSB4018 The "HotRestart.Tasks.DetectSigningIdentity" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.iOS.Windows.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)
File name: 'Xamarin.iOS.Windows.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.Tasks.DetectSigningIdentity.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()

    OhMyGod C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk\15.2.302-preview.14.122\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets    20```
Please help on this.
````

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue that is also mentioned in this reported issue: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3980

Should be fixed with the next round of updates!

Comment: I am still facing this issue :(